# How to make field instructions show as tooltip?

Tags: craft3, control-panel, field, css, field-instructions

How to turn

[image]

show as the following style

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Install control panel CSS plugin, and add the following style.

```
.field .heading{
  position: relative;
}

.field.tooltip-icon-append label:after{
    content: "i";
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: open-sans;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative!important;
    top: 0!important;
    left: 0!important;
    color: #fff;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 5px!important;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: rgba(0,135,255,.7);
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: auto;
}

.field .heading .instructions {
    visibility: hidden;
    max-width: 100vw;
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    bottom: 150%;
    width: 300px;
    opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(205,216,228,.25), 0 2px 12px rgba(205,216,228,.5);
    transition: opacity .3s;
}

.field .instructions::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 25px;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ddd transparent transparent;
}

.field .heading:hover .instructions {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Install control panel JS plugin and add the following code.

```
    $(".field>.heading").each(function(){
        var instruction = $(this).find(".instructions");
        if(instruction.length !== 0){
            $(this).parent().addClass("tooltip-icon-append");
        }
    });
```